# Django share requests.session() between views

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-requests

I make 2-3 calls to an API URL per view and using requests.session() cuts down the connection time by a significant amount. Is there a way to keep the session open between views to avoid the initial setup time?

I'm looking for something like [persistent database connections](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/databases/#persistent-connections) but for sessions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what can help you in session persistence in database, but you can try to optimize the time by changing the [Session Engine of Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/sessions/).